# move window to corner and RESIZE in gnome shell

Tags: gnome, window-manager, mutter

in Unity with the `CTRL-ALT-KeyPad_7` keybinding I can move a window to the top-left corner and it is automatically resized to a quarter of my desktop size.

In gnome-shell, in `dconf`, I found the relevant option for gnome-shell:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings
```

`move_to_corner_nw`, however this just moves the window, without actually resizing it.

Would you have any hint?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to place windows with keyboard shortcuts in Gnome-Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84066/is-it-possible-to-place-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-shell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, the `Put Windows` extension does exactly what I was looking for:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/

Answer (score 1):

This is just an addition to the answer from Andrea Zonca.

1. Install GNOME Shell extension [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)
2. Execute `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` from terminal
3. Go to the settings of **Put Windows**
4. Configure it, done.